# Expo keeps on changing Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, node-modules

In my React Native Expo App there are few things I have to change in the node-modules folder to make my app work correctly.

For example I change the AppEntry.js file to select the navigator file as a start file for my app which works great. Also I have to adjust the metro-bundler blacklist.js - which also doesn't cause any problems.

> But when I restart/rebuild the app it seems like every change I made
> is discarded and put back to default.. Is this normal?

Is there a way we can persist the settings - because it gets annoying having to change this on every start. Yesterday I spend 3 hours finding a fix and after I finally found one and installed a new package so I had to restart the app again the errors appeared again and I didn't know why but now I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my React Native Expo App there are few things I have to change in the node-modules folder to make my app work correctly.

You should never have to edit stuff in `node_modules`. Of course you might feel forced to do that because of some bug, but in general you should avoid this and find a better way to fix the problem.

> For example I change the AppEntry.js file to select the navigator file as a start file for my app

Could you instead have a more or less empty `App.js` that imports from “the navigator file” and re-exports it? Or could you rename your “navigator file” to `App.js`?

> Also I have to adjust the metro-bundler blacklist.js

For this, I believe you should rather “[Customize Metro](https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro/)”.

By the way, I don’t think `expo start` changes stuff in `node_modules`, or I would be very surprised if it did, but `yarn` or `npm` (or `expo install`) would.

Comment: yh its rather the installing of new things that changes the code. Still why is that tho?

Comment: I changed the AppEntry to my navigator threw App.js works ! - the blacklist problem isnt that bad tbh because if it changes I know where to fix it.

Comment: Well, the purpose of `yarn` and `npm` is to manage the installation of packages which they do by updating stuff in `node_modules`.

Comment: is it possible to change node module file and apply that changes in application?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve by doing that? I don't completely understand what you mean.

Comment: Expo does change node module on startup. It's really annoying actually. There is nothing wrong whatsoever with changing a package. Sometimes the package doesn't work how you want it to, but it a slightly modified version would work perfectly and save a lot of time. `You should never have to edit stuff in node_modules.` is just not true at all.

Comment: @ICW if you need to for some reason, use `patch-package`. Also, please explain when Expo changes node_modules?